# Jquery Javascript HTML selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

So I've got a standard select dropdown. One of the options in the select(the last one) I've got as a text string- var abc.

```
<select id="exampleselect">
     <option>123</option>
     <option>xyz</option>
     <option>ABC</option>
</select>

var abc = "ABC";
```

What I'm trying to do is search through the select, find a match against var abc then change the match of var abc to being the selected option.

What I've tried:

```
//gets all the options from the select
var selectoptions = $('#exampleselect').find('option').text(); 

//if there is a match of var abc to any of the options in the select
if (selectoptions == abc)
    {
       //work out how to get the index/eq of the matched element

       //put matched element as selected value
       $('#exampleselect').val(matchedelementindex);
    }
```

Comment: So you want the last option to be dynamic? how will the value be set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/LC3zR/).

As you don't use the value attribute, you can use this code:

```
var myVar = 'xyz';

$('#exampleselect option').each(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text() === myVar) {
        $this.prop('selected', true);
        return false; // stops the iteration
    }
});
```

You could also do it in one line by using the `:contains()` selector. **But** this would may not work if you have an option with text "ABC" and another with "ABCD":

```
$('#exampleselect option:contains('+myVar+')').prop('selected', true);
```

---

Although, I would recommend that you add a value attribute to your option elements:

```
<select id="exampleselect">
     <option value="123">123</option>
     <option value="xyz">xyz</option>
     <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
</select>
```

this way you can do:

```
$('#exampleselect').val(myVar);
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting the use of `value`. A much more succinct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var abc = "ABC";
$("#exampleselect option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == abc) {
        $(this).attr("selected", true);
        return false; // exit each loop
    }
})
```

Or this, although this is slightly less readable:

```
var abc = "ABC";
$("#exampleselect option").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("selected", $(this).text() == abc);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle may help you .
You can achieve this by CSS Selectors which are supported by jQuery

```
var searched="abc";
$('select option['+searched+']').attr("selected","selected");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7EzqU/

Answer (score 0):

```
// iterate all select options using jquery .each method    
$('#exampleselect option').each(function () {

    // check if current option text is equal to 'ABC'
    if ($(this).text() == 'ABC') {

        // get index of option
        var index = $('#exampleselect').index($(this))

        // set selectedIndex property to change to this option
        $('#exampleselect').prop('selectedIndex', index);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick:
http://jsfiddle.net/xXEVw/